# '80s or '90s movie that begins with a small spaceship docking with a larger one, and the captain entering a bar

Tags: story-identification, movie, space, robots

I was hoping someone could help me find the name of a movie that was released sometime between through the '80s and '90s.

I remember it starting out with a smaller space ship docking to a larger one; the captain of the smaller vessel possibly mentions running robots (maybe sex androids.) I remember him (the captain of the smaller ship) entering a bar not too long after arriving, speaking to a bar tender about how "he's got damages " to his ship, and him telling another patron to "hey... get your own beer."

It seemed to be a low budget film, no recognizable stars by any means, just a cheesey late night Cinemax-type movie that I found to have laughably great one liners.

It is not *Cherry 2000*.

Comment: This sounds like the flavor of either *Metalstorm* or *Ice Pirates*, 1983 and 1984 respectively, but it's been decades since I've seen either one and I don't recall this level of detail.  Almost resembles *Moon Zero-Two* as well, but that's a decade or more older.

Comment: Thank you so much ~ I'll take a look at those

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like **Space Truckers** (1996)

John Canyon (played by Dennis Hopper) is an independant Space Trucker with an old, beat up space rig. He docks after off-loading a shipment of square pigs to refuel and get a bite. I don't recall the beer line, though. To make the bills, he takes on a load of sex dolls headed to Earth. Or, at least, that's what HE thinks!

Comment: Thank you so much ~ I checked it out and unfortunately it wasn't the movie ~ Thank you for your help though